# Where can I see a full list of Classify["FacebookTopic"] results?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, machine-learning, social-media

I can see that `Classify` function has some built in classifiers, like `"FacebookTopic"`. For example, if I type "Should I take an umbrella?" the function returns "Weather". And that is awesome.

I am looking for a full list of possible topics, I want my program to take decision based on that.

Comment: Have you seen the built-in classifiers mentioned in the documentation for `Classify`? Those are "CountryFlag", "FacebookTopic", "Language", "NameGender", "NotablePerson", "Profanity", "Sentiment", "Spam". Perhaps others exist, but they might not be fully documented.

Comment: Yes, I have seen them. I am looking for a full list of possible results returned from the built in classifiers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how:

```
Classify["FacebookTopic"]
ClassifierInformation[%, "Classes"]
```

> `{"Books", "CareerAndMoney", "SocialMedia",  "FamilyAndFriends",
>   "Fashion", "Fitness", "FoodAndDrink", "Health",  "Technology",
>   "Leisure", "QuotesAndLifePhilosophy", "Relationships",  "Movies",
>   "Music", "PersonalMood", "PetsAndAnimals", "Politics", 
>   "SchoolAndUniversity", "SpecialOccasions", "Sports", "Television", 
>   "Transport", "Travel", "VideoGames", "Weather"}`

Comment: Did not know about the ClassifierInformation function, thanks! It can return classes for any other ClassifierFunction as well.